# Perl Win32::GuidGen format

Tags: perl

I have the following code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32;    
my $guid = Win32::GuidGen();

print $guid;
```

which generates GUID like this  {77C71DCC-8825-4B37-A8D3-C0400C885DBB}

I am wondering if there are an option to return the guid in this format

77c71dcc-8825-4b37-a8d3-c0400c885dbb

instead of adding the following code

```
 $guid =~ s/^{|}$//g;
 $guid= lc($guid);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Win32::GuidGen() does not have any such options.

`Win32::GuidGen()` simply [returns](https://metacpan.org/release/JDB/Win32-0.59/source/Win32.xs#L715) the string provided by the [OS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/combaseapi/nf-combaseapi-stringfromclsid).

Faster:

```perl
my $guid = lc( substr( Win32::GuidGen(), 1, -1 ) );
```